# how to set my view's id to be my model's id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm a beggineer with BackBone.js and i want my rendered `el` to be

```
<div class="rectangle" id="ITEM_ID_OF_MY_MODEL"</div>
```

now setting the class `.rectangle` is easy using the `className` property and the problem is setting the `id` of the View.

```
var Rectangle = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        item_id: this.cid
    }
});

var RectangleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'rectangle',

    initiliaze: function() {
        this.id = this.model.get('item_id');
    },
    events: {
        'click': 'move'
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.model.cid); // prints c1 then c2 then c3
        this.setDimensions();
        this.setPosition();
        this.setColor();
        return this;
    },
    setPosition: function() {
        var position = this.model.get('position');
        this.$el.css({
            left: position.x,
            top: position.y
        });
    },
    setDimensions: function() {
        this.$el.css({
            width: this.model.get('width') + 'px',
            height: this.model.get('height') + 'px'
        });
    },
    setColor: function() {
        this.$el.css('background-color', this.model.get('color'));
    },
    move: function() {
        this.$el.css('left', this.$el.position().left + 10);
    }

});

var props1 = {
    width: 100,
    height: 60,
    position: {
        x: 300,
        y: 150
    },
    color: 'tomato',
    item_id: 1
}
var props2 = {
    width: 200,
    height: 20,
    position: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    },
    color: 'grey',
    item_id: 2
}
var props3 = {
    width: 140,
    height: 160,
    position: {
        x: 200,
        y: 300
    },
    color: 'blue',
    item_id: 3
}

var models = [
    new Rectangle(props1),
    new Rectangle(props2),
    new Rectangle(props3)
];

_(models).each(function(model) {
    var myView = new RectangleView({model: model});
    var myRenderedElement = myView.render().el;
    $('#canvas').append(myRenderedElement)
});
```

the erros is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

and instead, if i do this:

```
id: this.model.cid
```

i get a similar error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cid' of undefined
```

so `this.model.get('item_id')` is trying to access a model which has not been loaded to the view yet. (`this.model` is `undefined`)

**how can i set my view's id to be my model's id?**

+ thank you for your answer and also your time.

Comment: have you tried setting the value inside the initialize method of the view? without looking at the source, it appears the model hasn't been set by the time it's trying to set the id on construction

Comment: i now update the post and put the full code, i thought i was doing a good thing just putting the problem

Comment: You should be able to `id: function() { return this.model.get('item_id') }` instead. I have to run or I'd give you a real answer.

Comment: and the initialize function does not give the el the id.

Comment: @muistooshort, it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the id or class of your view in your render function. Remember that this.el refers to the view element. So we can then change any property of the element we choose to.

```js
render: function()
{
    this.el.id = this.model.cid; // this line here
    var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());

    this.$el.html(template);
    return this; 
}
```